# Error when run - docker-compose up for mac

Tags: docker

When I Run docker-compose up, I get this error on my mac.

Starting php_server ... error

ERROR: for php_server  Cannot start service php-server: Mounts denied:
The path /usr/local/var/www/html/docker-tutorials/src
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.

ERROR: for php-server  Cannot start service php-server: Mounts denied:
The path /usr/local/var/www/html/docker-tutorials/src
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

and this is file docker-compose.yaml.

```
version: "2"

services:
  php-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "9000"
    container_name: php_server
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
        APP_ENV: dev
  
  nginx-server:
    build: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    container_name: nginx_server
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php-server
```

Comment: And have you tried what the error message suggests? Does the path (`/usr/local/var/www/html/docker-tutorials/src`) exist on your mac?

Comment: sure. yes of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. and must share it with you.

To fix:
Go to docker preferences and add the folder path in the ‘File Sharing’ section

click: apply & restart docker
docker run ... again

the solution from this is a link.

https://medium.com/@lynzt/learning-docker-error-mounts-denied-mac-73307b49f545